# How to implement a thread safe central object/list that can be accessed without concurrency exceptions?

Tags: android, thread-safety, locking, android-service

I'm having some trouble with implementing a thread safe way to centrally update and access a list of class objects in my Android app. This is an open type of question, where not a lot of source code can be given.

Basically I have an app with an Activity and Service. The Service implements a UDP broadcasting task and a UDP broadcast listening task. The broadcasted information is essentially a JSON serialized copy of a class that represents the device. e.g. UUID, IP, some administrative info like a user set name, description, etc... The JSON is stored in the UDP packet and sent, the UDP packet is received and de-serialized and processed. That de-serialized class is stored in a Hashtable and the current instance belongs to the Service. e.g. everyone that wants access to the data has to go through the Service. The whole thing is very async.

The Activity binds to the service (via and extension of Binder) so it can call Service methods, like start/stop the UDP tasks. The Activity will listen for Android Intents that the Service will issue when any updates or new device data has been received, and the UI will display information related to the received UDP packet data. Note again the the packet data is stored in a container class belonging to the Service.

The problem is I can't figure out a suitable way to make the Hashtable of received data thread safe. I get java.util.ConcurrentModificationException errors when the data is grabbed from a Service method, then processed. If the data is updated while I'm processing it in a loop (iterator or for), a ConcurrentModificationException will happen. I know where, when and why, but using lock() or a ReentrantLock() is typically leveraged within a method call of the class that has the data to be locked, not on single point data that's returned for processing outside that container class. Something like: (where I'm using syncronized, not ReentrantLock(), its just an example)

```
public class sampleLockClass {
    private Hashtable<String, String> sampleData = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    public sampleLockClass() {}
    public synchronized put(String s1, String s2) {
        this.sampleData().put(s1, s2);
    }
    public synchronized Hashtable<String, String> getAll() {
        return this.sampleData; // This is returned for the processing outside the class
    }
}
```

In this case, the getAll() method is returning sampleData Hashtable as it is needed for processing outside the class itself. The reason for this is that data is passed to other APIs I'm leveraging, and they're not compatible with this approach. e.g. they expect there to be a single, thread safe copy for its use.

Maybe this is a dumb or non-issue, but how would you go about making the returned sampleData thread safe for the period its needed? Note that for right now only the Service would write to the sampleData. Everything else is read-only, and I likely would try to commit any updates to the sampleData from Activity through the CommService via an Intent.

Would it be safer to try to make a copy of the Hashtable sampleData for each get() method?

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

> A hash table supporting full concurrency of retrievals and adjustable
> expected concurrency for updates. This class obeys the same functional
> specification as Hashtable, and includes versions of methods
> corresponding to each method of Hashtable.
>
> Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block, so may
> overlap with update operations (including put and remove). Retrievals
> reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations
> holding upon their onset. For aggregate operations such as putAll and
> clear, concurrent retrievals may reflect insertion or removal of only
> some entries.
>
> The allowed concurrency among update operations is guided by the
> optional concurrencyLevel constructor argument (default 16), which is
> used as a hint for internal sizing. The table is internally
> partitioned to try to permit the indicated number of concurrent
> updates without contention. Because placement in hash tables is
> essentially random, the actual concurrency will vary.
>
> **public Collection values()**
>
> Returns a Collection view of the values contained in this map. The collection is backed
> by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the collection, and vice-versa.
> The collection supports element removal, which removes the
> corresponding mapping from this map, via the Iterator.remove,
> Collection.remove, removeAll, retainAll, and clear operations. It does
> not support the add or addAll operations. The view's iterator is a
> "weakly consistent" iterator that will never throw
> **ConcurrentModificationException**, and guarantees to traverse elements as they existed upon construction of the iterator, and may
> (but is not guaranteed to) reflect any modifications subsequent to
> construction.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I switched to ConcurrentHashMap but it didn't do the trick. Basically any change to the contents of an object in the ConcurrentHashMap is still subject to concurrency. For example, the Hashmap values are a container class, that can have its contents updated from different threads. The returned ConcurrentHashMap contains stuff that can throw the ConcurrentModificationException. If I was only using the ConcurrentHashMap, this might do the trick.

Comment: It seems that Collection got from value() will **never** throw ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: Ya, the values() call won't, but if you have something in the returned values that can, it will throw the exception.

Comment: can you give me a specific example?